# Add item to child collection with values from form

Tags: knockout.js

I''ve read alot of articles the last few days, and quickstarts, and tutorials but more or less all of them, when adding an item to a observable array pushes a empty item, and lets the user fill out the rest after creation, but i want to go the other way around.

The knockout bidings below are working as far as the dropdown list is populated and the button is disabled if textarea is empty, but that is all I've got so far.

My view models and data i use is found here: [Child collection mapping not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199726/child-collection-mapping-not-firing) 
I dont know if i should copy them here, or keep them in the seperate thread for readability

What I wish to achive is to add a new observable item to my collection "Texts" with a language from the drop down list and a text from the textarea when clicking the button.

This part below is a small part of the content of a bootstrap modal bound to a "selectedItem" of a collection on my root view model.

```
    <div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-bind="showModal:selectedItem, with:selectedItem">
    <!-- Here is code for enumerating from collection "Texts", but i removed it for readability, and put focus on the "Add part" below  -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label col-md-offset-2">Language</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select data-bind="options: $root.AvailableLanguages, optionsText:'Name', optionsValue:'Id'" class="form-control"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label col-md-offset-2">Translation</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <textarea class="form-control" data-bind='value: $root.itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"'></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label col-md-offset-2"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-bind="click: addItem, enable: $root.itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button></label>
                </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle demonstrating what you can no get to work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cSE5X/2/ - I have never used JSFiddle so i dont know what to add there, but that is a basically what i have today.

If i bind addValues to submit on the form-tag it is not fired, and the page get posted, but if I bind it to click on the button it get fired, but if i debug using alert(ko.toJSON(element)), i get the model in "selectedItem", and not from my form.

Comment: Sorry, i still can't work out what you are trying to do. At the simplest level what are you trying to achieve? Strip out anything that does not matter and tell me the exact problem. It sounds like you just want to click a button and have a new item added to a collection that has two values, one from a drop down and another from a text box, is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. I have been very diffuse in my description. I want to click a button, and get values from a dropdown and a textarea and insert it into a child collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken your comment into consideration and produced this fiddle. I hope it helps.

Notice how the model keeps track of the two items you care about, the drop down and textbox.

It then adds a new item to the observable array (based on these two things) when you click `Add Item`.

Knockout is doing all the magic for me and all i have done is set up some bindings really.

## ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kohan/MK3PD/))

## Js

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.CurrentDropDownItem = ko.observable("");
    self.CurrentTextBoxItem = ko.observable("4imble");

    self.Greetings = ko.observableArray([new GreetingItem("Hello", "RandomPerson")]);

    self.SaveNewGreeting = function(){
            self.Greetings.push(new GreetingItem(self.CurrentDropDownItem(), self.CurrentTextBoxItem()));
    }

    return {
        CurrentDropDownItem: CurrentDropDownItem,
        CurrentTextBoxItem: CurrentTextBoxItem,
        Greetings: Greetings,
        SaveNewGreeting: SaveNewGreeting
    }
}

function GreetingItem(greeting, name){
    var self = this;
    self.greeting = greeting;
    self.name = name;    
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

## Html

```
<div>
    <select data-bind="value: CurrentDropDownItem">
        <option>Hello</option>
        <option>Goodbye</option>
        <option>How you doing?</option>
    </select>    

    <input type="text" data-bind="value: CurrentTextBoxItem, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></input>
    <button data-bind="click: SaveNewGreeting">Add Item</button>
</div>

<div>

<h3>Dynamically Generated List</h3>
    This is the list of items added so far (1st added at run time):
    <div data-bind="foreach: Greetings">
        <b data-bind="text: greeting"></b>, 
        <b data-bind="text: name"></b><br />
    </div>

<h3>Debug Status Messages</h3>
    This is the value currently bound to drop down: 
        <b data-bind="text: CurrentDropDownItem"></b><br />
    This is the value currently bound to the text box: 
        <b data-bind="text: CurrentTextBoxItem, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></b>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was a great start of what i was looking for. I even combined it with a "with"-data bind to be able to edit as well as add. Now i have a better grasp of how I should wrap my mind around knckout!